# How to disable checkbox one after another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two checkboxes with different names:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="checkbox2">
```

I'd like to implement code where when checkbox1 is checked, checkbox2 is disabled and when checkbox2 is checked, checkbox1 is disabled. When it's unchecked, it should enable the other back as well.

How can I achieve with jQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I'm assuming the work you want to do cannot be done via Radio Buttons because that's the obvious choice here. In case it can, here's a few links for that:
http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_are_the_differences_between_radio_buttons_and_checkboxes
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

```
Checkbox 1: <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" onchange="onCheckboxChanged();"/>
Checkbox 2: <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" onchange="onCheckboxChanged();"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Initialize checkboxes
    onCheckboxChanged();
</script>
```

Js:

```
var onCheckboxChanged = function(checkbox){
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById('checkbox2');

    if(checkbox1.checked){
        checkbox2.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
        checkbox2.disabled = false;
    }

};
```

Comment: yes, with my current form structures, it won't be able to use with radio buttons that's why. Your code works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: But that function only tests `checkbox1`, it doesn't do anything when `checkbox2` is checked. (Also, you can replace the if/else structure with one line: `checkbox2.disabled=checkbox1.checked;`.)

Answer (score 2):

try this code,

html,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="checkbox1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="checkbox2"/>​​​​​​​​
```

javascript,

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('[type="checkbox"]').not(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('[type="checkbox"]').not(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    }

});​
```

demo

http://jsfiddle.net/rsxXd/

Comment: One downside to this solution is that it will affect ALL checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

here is jquery example http://jsfiddle.net/XnQzQ/

```
$('input[name=checkbox1]').click(function() { 
        if($('input[name=checkbox1]').is(':checked'))
        {
        $('input[name=checkbox2]').attr("disabled", "disabled")
        }
        else
         {
         $('input[name=checkbox2]').removeAttr( "disabled");
         }
    });
   $('input[name=checkbox2]').click(function() { 
    if($('input[name=checkbox2]').is(':checked'))
    {
    $('input[name=checkbox1]').attr("disabled", "disabled")
    }
    else
    {
     $('input[name=checkbox1]').removeAttr( "disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It's quite long for me but it works. Thank you alot.

Comment: `$('input[name=checkbox1]').is(':checked')` can be replaced with `this.checked` - easier to read and type, and more efficient at runtime...

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the overkill of jQuery and just use pure JavaScript.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="checkbox1" onchange="checker()" />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="checkbox2" onchange="checker()" />​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function checker() {
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById('checkbox2');

    checkbox1.disabled = checkbox2.checked;
    checkbox2.disabled = checkbox1.checked;
}​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fEpWJ/

Comment: Thanks for the pure javascript. It works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: `checkbox1.disabled = checkbox2.checked;` is enough, you don't need the `?:` operator.

Comment: Good point since the result of true or false sets the disabled state.

Answer (score 0):

Simple with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $cbs = $('input[type="checkbox"][name^="checkbox"]').click(function() {
       $cbs.not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked);
   });​
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j6Jpz/

Though if the idea is to prevent both checkboxes being checked at the same time I'd suggest it is nicer for the user if you leave both enabled but when one is checked automatically uncheck the other:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $cbs = $('input[type="checkbox"][name^="checkbox"]').click(function() {
      if (this.checked) $cbs.not(this).prop('checked', false);
   });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j6Jpz/1/

Note: the selector I've used, `'input[type="checkbox"][name^="checkbox"]'`, says to find all inputs of type checkbox with a name that starts with "checkbox". This could be simplified to `'input.someClass'` if you gave a common class, `class="someClass"`, to the inputs in question.

Note also that either version of my code will automatically handle larger groups of checkboxes.